# How to compare a list with a list of list and move them according to the list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got this list

```
['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
```

and a list of list:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0,a], [1, 0, 2, 0,c], [1, 2, 0, 0,w], [0, 0, 0, 0,Q], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
```

and I want to swap the items according to my list with the alphabets?So my output will be:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0,a], [1, 0, 2, 0,c], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'],[1, 2, 0, 0,w],[0, 0, 0, 0,Q], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
```

EDIT:The numbers have to be moved along with the alphabet.

Comment: Your example is not at all clear just how items are replaced. Please give a verbal description of what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
ll = [[0, 1, 1, 0,'a'], [1, 0, 2, 0,'c'], [1, 2, 0, 0,'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0,'Q'], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]

sorted(ll, key=lambda x: l.index(x[-1]))
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 'a'],
 [1, 0, 2, 0, 'c'],
 [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'],
 [1, 2, 0, 0, 'w'],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 'Q'],
 [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'],
 [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
a1 = ['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
a2 = [[0, 1, 1, 0,'a'], [1, 0, 2, 0,'c'], [1, 2, 0, 0,'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0,'Q'], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
new_dict = {i[-1]:i for i in a2}
new_list = [new_dict[i] for i in a1]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0, 'a'], [1, 0, 2, 0, 'c'], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [1, 2, 0, 0, 'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 'Q'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]
```

Comment: I need the numbers to move together with the alphabets as well.For example,[2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'],[1, 2, 0, 0,w]...etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can try this :

```
list_a = ['a', 'c', 'g', 'w', 'Q', 'front', 'Z']
list_b = [[0, 1, 1, 0,'a'], [1, 0, 2, 0,'c'], [1, 2, 0, 0,'w'], [0, 0, 0, 0,'Q'], [2, 0, 0, 15, 2, 'g'], [12, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2, 'front'], [0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 'Z']]


sorted_list=[]
for i in list_a:
    for j in list_b:
        if i==j[-1]:
            sorted_list.append(j)

print(sorted_list)
```

In one line solution :

```
print([j for i in list_a for j in list_b if i==j[-1]])
```